# Is there a comprehensive C# linter and formatter like eslint for JS/TS?

Tags: c#, .net, lint, code-formatting

I'd like to have my C# projects (.NET Core 3.1+) to be linted and formatted on each build both locally and in CI environment. I know that there's new .NET Analyzers feature and `dotnet-format` tool in .NET 6, but I can't understand from the documentation if I can make a single comprehensive configuration file that both these tools would use so I can enforce certain code style in my team. Could you help me understand if it is possible?

Comment: have you checked the [code analysis documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/roslyn-analyzers-overview?view=vs-2022) ?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Yes there is - Roslyn Analyzers.

With a `EnforceCodeStyleInBuild` element set in your `.csproj`:

```xml
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>

    <!-- this! -->
    <EnforceCodeStyleInBuild>true</EnforceCodeStyleInBuild>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

an `.editorconfig` file in your project, which you can get like this:

```
dotnet new editorconfig
```

and updating your VS Code `settings.json` to include:

```json
{
  "omnisharp.enableRoslynAnalyzers": true,
  "omnisharp.enableEditorConfigSupport": true
}
```

And you should be off to the races! I've written this up in more depth here:

https://johnnyreilly.com/eslint-your-csharp-in-vs-code-with-roslyn-analyzers

Comment: what if we use VIsual Studio?

Comment: @Dorklord If I'm not mistaken latest versions of Visual Studio (2022, maybe 2019) understand `.editorconfig`.